# Azure Durable Functions cannot return an Object because of circular JSON error

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-durable-functions

Written in JavaScript I have an Activity function that I would like to initialize and return an Object to the Orchestrator function. The Object is initialized but cannot be return because of "Exception: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON". Is there anyway to return an Object back to the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error message => `Exception: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`

from your activity function you are returning something like this =>

```
var a = {};
a.b = a;
```

When activity function returns object back to it Orchestrator, internally it makes a json and in the Orchestrator it parses the json.

`JSON.stringify` can not convert structures like this.

Meaning activity functions can not return circular structure object.

You need to create a `non circular object` from the `circular object` and return it.